# Why I am unable to get the binary tree level order traversal from following code?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to do a level order traversal of a binary search tree and return the final result in a multi-dimensional array. eg. if **root node** is `2` and nodes at level 1 are `1,4` then it should return `[[2], [1,4]]` as `returnColumnSizes` from the code. I am new in *data structures* and don't have command in using `malloc` function as well. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

```
int height(struct TreeNode *h){
    if (h == NULL) return 0;
    int l = height(h->left);
    int r = height(h->right);
    if (l > r)
        return l+1;
    else
        return r+1;
}

int *ordercalc(struct TreeNode *root, int level){
    if (root == NULL) return NULL;
    int i = 0, arr[100];
    if (level == 1)
        arr[i++] = root->val;
    else if(level > 1){
        ordercalc(root->left, level-1);  //decrease the level one per call to print data when it
        ordercalc(root->right, level-1);  // reaches proper level
    }
    return arr;
}

int** levelOrder(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){
    if (*returnSize == 0) return NULL;
    **returnColumnSizes = (int **)malloc(*returnSize * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i=0;i<height(root)+1;i++){
        returnColumnSizes[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        returnColumnSizes[i] = ordercalc(root, i);
    }
    return returnColumnSizes;
}
```

Comment: In ordercalc you set i = 0 and then arr[i++] = root->val; you don't use `i` anymore, so this always sets arr[0] = root->val, after that `i` is incremented and forgotten.

Comment: `**returnColumnSizes = (int **)malloc(*returnSize * sizeof(int *));` looks wrong because `**returnColumnSizes` is of type `int`.

Comment: In `ordercalc`, `return arr;` is incorrect because the local array that the return value is pointing to is no longer valid once the function has returned.

Comment: How should I allocate memory for `**returnColumnSizes`?
I understood the rest. I'll make changes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`height` looks good.

`levelOrder` looks okay, although `i<height(root)+1;` computes the height of `root` again and again in the loop even though it doesn't change. Also, `malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);` doesn't seem sufficiently dynamic for large trees (we'll come back to this later).

`ordercalc` needs to be re-considered. The function has `arr[100];` allocated on its stack frame, then

```
if (level == 1)
    arr[i++] = root->val;
```

and

```
return arr;
```

I can see you're trying to fill the levels based on the height, which is the right idea. However:

1. Returning a stack-allocated array is undefined behavior. When the call returns, all data on its frame cannot be accessed. You'll need to `malloc` on the heap and return a pointer if you want to do this.
2. `arr[i++] = root->val;` puts the root at `arr[0]` but nothing else ever happens with this array, so the intent is unclear.
3. Hardcoding `100` for the array size seems a mistake. Surely there is some tree with a level large enough to overflow this buffer, assuming you intend to fill it up beyond the root. When you do switch to `malloc`, you'll probably need to plan to `realloc`.

Instead of returning results from this function, it seems that passing in a pointer to the pre-allocated result structure is simplest.

A way to simplify the reallocation and size management is to approach the problem with multiple passes. Here's the game plan:

1. Get the tree height.
2. Allocate the result and column size arrays to match tree height.
3. Perform a second traversal and set the result column lengths for each level.
4. Allocate each level to match the size determined in step 3.
5. Perform a final pass to populate the pre-allocated result levels.

Here's the code:

```
int height(struct TreeNode *root) {
    if (root) {
        int left = height(root->left);
        int right = height(root->right);
        return 1 + (left > right ? left : right);
    }

    return 0;
}

void set_col_lens(struct TreeNode *root, int *res_col_lens, int depth) {
    if (root) {
        res_col_lens[depth]++;
        set_col_lens(root->left, res_col_lens, depth + 1);
        set_col_lens(root->right, res_col_lens, depth + 1);
    }
}

void fill_levels(struct TreeNode *root, int **res, int *last_items, int level) {
    if (root) {
        int last_item = last_items[level]++;
        res[level][last_item] = root->val;
        fill_levels(root->left, res, last_items, level + 1);
        fill_levels(root->right, res, last_items, level + 1);
    }
}

int **level_order(struct TreeNode *root, int *res_len, int **res_col_lens) {
    if (!root) {
        *res_len = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    *res_len = height(root);
    int **res = malloc(sizeof(*res) * (*res_len));
    *res_col_lens = calloc(*res_len, sizeof(**res_col_lens));
    int *last_items = calloc(*res_len, sizeof(*last_items));
    set_col_lens(root, *res_col_lens, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < *res_len; i++) {
        res[i] = malloc(sizeof((*res)[i]) * (*res_col_lens)[i]);
    }

    fill_levels(root, res, last_items, 0);
    free(last_items);
    return res;
}
```

One benefit of this is that the problem is broken into simple, distinct steps.

Another approach which I think is more natural is to use a queue and perform a breadth-first traversal in one stack frame. The problem then becomes writing a queue abstraction in C, which is not difficult but does take a bit of fussing.

Comment: How does the line `res[i] = malloc(sizeof((*res)[i]) * (*res_col_lens)[i])` inside for loop works out? I cannot visualize the kind of memory being allocated here.

Comment: This allocates the memory for level `i` using the size of its pointer dereference and the corresponding `i`-th `res_col_len` value which we precomputed.

Comment: How does `sizeof(*res)` and `sizeof(**res_col_lens)` works out as *res is not a data type. So, what sizes are being referred to here?